# Multiple entityMangagerFactories ( 1PC pattern used) leads to java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'url' not set exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-orm, spring-data-commons

I have the Spring Maven project using Java 11. Jboss WIldfly 15.0.1 Final is my deployment server.

To import data (objects using Hibernate) from one data source to another data source (MySQL)- I have added one primary `entityManagerFactory` with `JpaTransactionManager` and I have 2 other entity manager factories separate `perisistenceUnits` and a `chainedTransactionManager` being used(for 1 Phase commit-1PC commnit).

When deploying the war, sometimes, I get the below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'someDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'onetimeConfig': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'entityMgrFactory2' defined in class path resource [com/path/ImportConfig.class]: Bean 
instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
 [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityMgrFactory2' threw exception;
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'url' not set
```

someDAO class header is:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
@Repository("someDAO")
public class SomeDAOImpl extends ParentDAOImpl implements SomeDAO {
```

The `someDAO` class extends the `ParentDAOImpl` class in which the primary `entityManagerFactory` is used and is also mentioned using `@DependsOn`. So, why does on deploy the creation of `someDAO` is trying to trigger the creation of `entityMgrFactory2` when `entityManagerFactory` is mentioned in?!

```
@Repository("parentDAOImpl")
@DependsOn({"entityManagerFactory"})
public class ParentDAOImpl implements ParentDAO, Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext
    private transient EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
```

The problem never replicates on my local machine. It does occurs only while deploying on other servers and deployment fails due to this. And also the exception sometimes mentions `someDAO` and other times a different `DAOclass` that extends `ParentDAOImpl`.

Please help me, I am a novice.